# Xamarin FFImageLoading and Glidex/Nuke compatibility

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-image, ffimageloading

In the past few days I got to know the glidex.forms and how it would be better for loading images in android. After some research I've found the [official Nuke page](https://github.com/roubachof/Xamarin.Forms.Nuke) where they teach how to install Nuke(for iOs) and Glidex. I thought they would recognize any image view(like ffimageloading cacheadImage), since nuke is from same author of ffimageloading, but now the application runs without images appearing, no error is displayed.

I noticed that FFImageLoading nuget packages has disappeared but I didn't unistall it. The strange is that my xaml project uses `<ffimageloading:cachedimage>` tags and it's compiling fine, even without ffimageloading package. I'm concerned about having to move all tags to `<Image>` to having everything working properly again, it would be a hard work. So I'm a little bit lost here and have a few questions:

- Does FFImageLoading CachedImage supposed to work with glidex/nuke automatically or I have to change all tags in .xaml code to `<Image>`?
- I really like FFImageLoading since it has some nice features like PlaceHolders, can I have ffimageloading working together nuke and glidex?

Comment: already found an answer?

Comment: @user3490546 unfortunately no. I went back to FFImageLoading. There is a minimal gain of performance but it's no big deal, so I have putted this in stand by for now.